# Arbitray variable/array type in fortran functions/subroutines

Tags: variables, fortran, subroutine

I hope this is not a too stupid question, but is it possible to have functions or subroutines where I can pass the type of an array like

```
subroutine foo(array, arr_type)
implicit none
arr_type, dimension(:) :: array

*Do something with array* 
end subroutine
```

or do I have to write a subroutine for each possible arr_type (e.g. integer, double precision,...) and overload the subroutine with an interface ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could experiment with Fortran 2003's *unlimited polymorphism*.  Write your subroutine a bit like this:

```
subroutine foo(array)
implicit none
class(*), dimension(:) :: array

! Do something with array

end subroutine
```

From the point of view of abbreviating code this won't save you much because you're likely to have to write something like

```
use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, only : real32, real64
.
.
.
select type (element=>array(1))
type is (real(real32))
    ! Code for 32-bit reals
type is (real(real64))
    ! Code for 64-bit reals
type is (integer)
    ! Code for integers of default kind
class is (shape)
    ! Code for shapes
class default
    ! Sweep up everything else
end select
```

But you may end up writing as many lines as if you follow Alexander Vogt's entirely sensible approach.

*EDIT, after comments*

What this approach won't deliver, because Fortran doesn't include its intrinsic types in any sort of type hierarchy, is a code such as

```
select type (element=>array(1))
class is (number)
    ! Code for any type and kind of Fortran number
```

That would be useful, but I don't see it happening soon.

Comment: I will test this approach. Depending on the problem it might shorten the code a bit since some operations and function do not explicitly depend on the type, eg. plus or minus. and only some parts need to be adjusted

Comment: Even + and - depend on type. In fact almost everything does. There is also a technique of using `include` for poor man templates http://objectmix.com/fortran/378796-fortran-templates-5.html .

Comment: @VladimirF There's also a very nice example of this in [Modern Fortran in Practice by Arjen Markus](http://amzn.com/1107603471) (pp. 73-75).

Answer (score 3):

Yes and no... You can bundle several functions/subroutines with different dummy arguments using an interface:

```
module foos
  interface foo
    module procedure foo_real
    module procedure foo_int
  end interface

contains

  subroutine foo_real( a )
    implicit none
    real,intent(inout) :: a(:)

    ! ...
  end subroutine

  subroutine foo_int( a )
    implicit none
    integer,intent(inout) :: a(:)

    ! ...
  end subroutine
end module
```

I know of no (simple) possibility to pass arrays with arbitrary *basic* type. You could take a look at [`transfer`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/TRANSFER.html) - but there be dragons ;-)